# Android signed APK can not make API calls

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic-cordova

Our app has started hanging when making API calls despite not being updated in production for months. We can replicate the issue using the Play Store version of the app or by creating a locally built APK file and signing it. However, we can not replicate the issue on browsers or a locally built unsigned APK files. If we make an action that makes an API call then leave the app for a couple of minutes, we see an "App isn't responding" message even though you can still navigate through the app.

Is there any way to fix this issue or see what caused the application to become unresponsive? I've tried looking at the network/debugging tab, but that doesn't seem possible on a signed device.

```
# Generate Key
keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000


# Sign the APK
jarsigner -verbose -sigalg SHA1withRSA -digestalg SHA1 -keystore my-release-key.keystore my_application.apk alias_name
```

Comment: It's not going to have anything to do with the signing-  debug builds are signed too.  They're signed with a key generated when you install Android Studio.  Most likely, you're hitting a different URL for release and debug builds to hit a staging environment and something is wrong with the release setup.  But you need to go through with a debugger and find out what's actually happening on a lower level, particularly what your network calls are doing and returning.

Comment: We're hitting the same URL. I ran `ionic cordova build android --release` to make the APK file then signed the apk file. Signing the app is the only difference I am aware of. How can we go through with a debugger if signing the app makes the app not debuggable?

Comment: Signing the app is not your problem.  All APKs are signed.  Even debug ones.  Android will refuse to run an unsigned APK.  Your issue is elsewhere.

Comment: Sorry if I'm missing something here but the app does run and it works properly until I sign it using the jarsigner command above. When I sign it, I run into the same issue we are running into in production. The confusing part is that the production app has been working for months and there haven't been any updates.

Comment: There are other differences in the prod release.  proguard is a likely suspect, as an answerer already suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue I posted in this question is the same issue/solution as the question I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71861868/android-apk-refuses-to-make-api-calls-if-debuggable-is-false). This issue was just presenting itself in a different way depending on how the application was built. For clarity, I have copied the solution from the other question below:

We found a solution. Issuing certificates from a different source server did the trick. The certificate, root certificate, and intermediary certificate were all valid, from what I could see. The Android application did not accept the certificates as valid for whatever reason. From what I could find, this may have occurred due to intermediary certificates expiring or Cordova using an old version of BoringSSL.

If anyone is running into this issue on a production/release build, go into the Android Manifest file and set Debuggable to true. The issue should go away. Then, rerun the production/release build with debuggable false, and the issue should reappear. Keep the production/release build on debuggable false and set android:usesCleartextTraffic to true. The issue should go away again. If you have the same results, you may be running into a similar issue where the application is not accepting the certificates (or you're using HTTP instead of HTTPS), and new certificates may solve the problem.

```
<application android:debuggable="true"android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled proguard `shrinkResources` & `modifiable` into gradle?
If yes then you have to add proguard rules for your model classes

Answer (score 0):

Check Internet Permission in Manifest

Example:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.dc.filetracker">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application android:label="File Tracker" android:name="${applicationName}" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"

        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        >
```

Answer (score 0):

In Ionic new version you need to go to manifest.xml under android and simply add `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` like this.

Also, if you are working in test mode and using http or https for API call you need to define the same in capacitor.config.ts file, where you need to add http or https for androidScheme property.

```
 webDir: 'www',
  server: {
    androidScheme: 'http',
  }
<application android:label="@string/app_name"
android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">

</application>
```